# when is an RDD sorted?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning Apache Spark and I have an early question about this. It seems like even when you sort an RDD, it can still come up unsorted depending on how you access it. Say I've performed sorting like this:

```
val someSortedRDD = someUnsortedRDD.map{[some condition]}.sortByKey()
```

This will always come up sorted:

```
someSortedRDD.collect()
```

However this will be printed in a potentially unsorted order, even though I previously sorted this RDD:

```
someSortedRDD.foreach(println)
```

So I'm just wondering if there are some general principles to follow to know when I'd be accessing an RDD in sorted vs unsorted order.

Comment: `foreach` is meant to run on the worker (in cluster mode, this actually doesn't show on the driver machine), not on the driver. So clearly sort order is not a concern (I think) - or execution goes by partition, etc. But `collect` always preserves sort order.

Comment: So why not promote to an answer?